# Updating ListView from Deserializing object

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application where I can add persons. They'll show up in a listview. Every time I add someone they appear. However, if I try too load a file the view will not refresh.

```
Persons = new List<Person>();
UsersListView.ItemsSource = Persons;

View = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(UsersListView.ItemsSource);

if (File.Exists("Persons.bin"))
{
    Persons = (List<Person>) Utils.Deserialize("Persons.bin");
    // The Persons list gets populated however, it doesn't show up in my view. 
    View.Refresh(); 
}

private void AddPersonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ValidateInfo())
    {
        Person person = new Person(FirstNameTextBox.Text, LastNameTextBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(AgeTextBox.Text));
        View.Refresh();
        Utils.Serialize(Persons, "Persons.bin");
    }
}
```

When I add a person via the button they view will refresh and they appear, but when I close and open the application the persons will not show up ever if my Persons list is populated.

Comment: Re-set the `ItemsSource`: `UsersListView.ItemsSource = (List<Person>) Utils.Deserialize("Persons.bin");`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, because if the file exists I dont set the ItemsSource. So there is nothing to Refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `ItemsSource` property to the new deserialized collection:

```
if (File.Exists("Persons.bin"))
{
    Persons = (List<Person>) Utils.Deserialize("Persons.bin");
    UsersListView.ItemsSource = Persons;
}
```

You may also want to look into data binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf

Comment: I'll accept the right answear as soon as I can. Notcied how ever, when I load the file it won't refresh my view with a new entry .

Comment: That's because you don't serialize the new entry and save it to the file. But that's another story really.